# Make default android autofill service remember not only login and password, but also a server address

Tags: android, autocomplete, autofill

I need to give user ability to enter server-name (where to login) and also login and password to login on that server.
I've tried to add autoFill hints, but Android autofill service only remembers login and password, and leaves server field empty. I've tried to use several different autoFill hints to server's field, but without any luck.

I'm using default Google Android autofill service.

Here is my dialog:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/please_next" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#8C8C8C"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/adress"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:autofillHints="name"
        android:textColor="@color/pure_black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#8C8C8C"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:autofillHints="username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#8C8C8C"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:autofillHints="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Are there any methods to make Android aitoFill service remember three fields on login procedure?

I've read google documentation, but didn't find any useful information.

Android development is not my specification (I'm backend programmer), so, maybe there are a lot of things unknown for me.

Comment: There is no single "Android aitoFill service". The actual autofill storage is handled by one of many possible apps. Whether they will store any given value is up to them.

Comment: Ok, it's default google autofill service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lots of investigation, I've came to conclusion that default google autoFill service can only remember multiple fields if there are no password field in form.

So, the simplest method of autoFill three fields - is to make it manually, by storing input fields values into application database if user have checked "save my credentials" checkbox, and If it's saved, read it back at startup.